# FileNotFoundException when referencing (managed) C++ Assembly from a C# Console App

Tags: c++-cli, console-application, .net-assembly, filenotfoundexception

I am in the process of writing a .NET wrapper for legacy native c++ code.  My strategy is to write a CLR class library that wraps the native code.

To test whether the class library is functioning properly, I created two console apps in separate solutions:

1. A C++ CLR console app
2. A C# console app

Both of these contain the same simple test code to exercise the class library.

Both apps build as expected.  The C++ app runs just fine, but the C# app is giving me a FileNotFoundException when it tries to load my class library.

I have a constraint that forces me to use VS2008 and .NET 3.5.  Everything is built with Win32 or x86 configurations.

For both console apps, I am using a project reference to the class library.

In each case, builds copy the dll (and the intermediate files) to the same directory where each app is built.

I tried using the fusion log viewer, but logs are disabled on my machine and I do not have administrator privileges.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Can someone please point me to a good site that outlines the differences between the way C# and C++ CLR apps load assemblies?

Since this is my first attempt to bridge C++ and C# I assume I am just making a simple mistake somewhere, but I am stumped as to what that is.

I have trolled the internet (including many SO postings) but have yet to find exactly what I need.

Thanks in advance,
Judd

Comment: Do you have the native libraries used by your wrapper in the path?  Failing that, did you copy them to the execution folder of both the C# and C++ test apps?  (There are ways to hook native libraries into a class library, but things get notoriously finicky)  PS - what is the native library?  C DLL?  C++ DLL? COM library?  Also, execution path moves around for C# depending on if you're debugging or running from command line.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  It was the path.  In the C++ version, I had all the native library paths specified.  In the C# one, I did not.  (See, I knew it had to be something simple).  I do not see a good way to specify the path when debugging the C# app.  Any suggestions?  Thanks again.  Judd

Comment: Very hard to help programmers that are not allowed to use the tools you need to get the job done.  I can only recommend [this site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).  Try SysInternals' ProcMon.